# How to disable a Gallery's item?

Tags: android, gallery, baseadapter

I have a gallery where I have implement a custom adapter extending the BaseAdapter. For some items, I want them to be disabled, and not clickable as well.

Overriding the isEnabled(int) method doesn't work. I am still able to click on the disabled items, and then, the gallery centers this item inside it.

Any ideas?

Comment: try setFocusable(false); might work

Comment: This also doesn't work. The onItemClick event gets called.

Comment: can you paste your some code or come to this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following is the relevant source code of gallery widget

```
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

     if (mDownTouchPosition >= 0) {

         // An item tap should make it selected, so scroll to this child.
         scrollToChild(mDownTouchPosition - mFirstPosition);

         // Also pass the click so the client knows, if it wants to.
         if (mShouldCallbackOnUnselectedItemClick || mDownTouchPosition == mSelectedPosition) {
             performItemClick(mDownTouchView, mDownTouchPosition, mAdapter
                     .getItemId(mDownTouchPosition));
         }

         return true;
     }

     return false;
 }
```

As you can see, the gallery scrolls to the tapped child item before performing the click on it. 
So the only way you can truly disable an item is by extending `Gallery` and overriding `onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)` in it.

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    int itemPosition = pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
    if (item at itemPosition is disabled) {
        // Do nothing.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
}
```

Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code where you can handle the click event for specific positions. Also you can disable the specific items.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{
    private Activity _activity;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Gallery g = new Gallery(this);
                g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
                setContentView(g);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                R.drawable.menu1,
                R.drawable.menu2,
                R.drawable.menu3,
                R.drawable.menu4,
                R.drawable.menu1,
                R.drawable.menu2,
                R.drawable.menu3,
                R.drawable.menu4
        };

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
            if(position!=0){
            i.setEnabled(false);
            i.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```